# SharePoint 2010, CAML query to see if a new item has been added to a list (Announcements)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

all.  I am trying to build a CAML query for a SP2010 list that will check the Announcements to see if anything new has been added (or a CAML query + some functionality).  I do not truly understand CAML and SP yet and would be grateful for any help - thank you.

Comment: To understand more about CAML:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx
If you still have questions show how it has to be your filter, you can be in any language that I help build query in caml

Answer (score 0):

Have a look around an SPQuery object if you want to go down the CAML route.
You will want to get all the items for a given date/time range unless you have a field that flags if an item is new..... the link below should help you build a query

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fed59f8e-72e2-46e2-9329-460fd65d7536/caml-query-datetime

Once you have a SPQuery object pass it to the SPList GetItems() method

You will then have a collection of items what you do with them then is all up to you :)

Hope this helps